# React Scratchcard Customization

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am writing this post concerning a Scratchcard component for React. This is the link: https://github.com/crowdland/react-scratch-me

At this moment I am dealing with the following issue:

Piece of code:
onCompleted ={ () => myFunction}
completedAt = {60}

See the code above where completedAt is assigned with 60. When this is true then onCompleted will run myFunction. This works fine and is intended to. However because completedAt is true, myFunction will continuously run.

Want I want is myFunction to run ONCE when completedAt is true (until the next render). I am wondering if anyone could help with this customization. Much appreciated for reading my post. Thank you all!

With Kind Regards,
a fellow potato programmer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can manage that with state

**example**

```
const [completed, setCompleted] = useState(false)
// your function
const myFunction = () => {
 if(!completed){
  //do what you want here
  setCompleted(true)
 }
}
```